# Enable or disable FCM push notifications by toggle button from application settings

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented push notifications through Firebase in my app. The notification is coming even when the notification is disabled from settings.
The classes I have implemented for Firebase are:

```
    public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

            private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
            @Override
            public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

                //Displaying data in log

                Log.e(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
                //Calling method to generate notification

                String to="";
                to = remoteMessage.getData().get("key1");

        //when the notification is disabled then also the notification is coming
     if(notification_enable) {
    sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(),remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(),to);
           }
        }

            //This method is only generating push notification
            //It is same as we did in earlier posts
            private void sendNotification(String title,String messageBody,String to) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Splash_Activity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("key1",to);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);


                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

                Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.noti_icon)
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(messageBody))
                        .setContentText(messageBody)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent))
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

                NotificationManager notificationManager =
                        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
            }
        }
 public class FirebaseIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    private static final String TAG = "FirebaseIDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.e(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    /**
     * Persist token to third-party servers.
     *
     * Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any server-side account
     * maintained by your application.
     *
     * @param token The new token.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // Add custom implementation, as needed.
    }
}
```

And included the classes in manifest as:

```
<permission
        android:name="com.pixelpoint.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.pixelpoint.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".FirebaseIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Are you sending the notification using the Firebase Console? 
These notifications will be handled by the system if the app is in the background and your `MyFirebaseMessagingService` wont receive a callback. Your code that does a client side check for if a user is registered in local settings to receive a notification won't work for all cases. (More about background processing here https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive)

My suggestion for this is to create a topic and automatically subscribe the user to that topic straight after registering the user:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("news");
```

Then when the user toggles the notification **off**, unsubscribe them from the topic.

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic("news");
```

This will remove them from the list on the server, and you wont be relying on client side logic to filter out unwanted notifications.

Then when sending notification to the client from Firebase Console, you should then **only target those users that are registered for that topic**.

More about Topic Messaging here - https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging

Comment: what is this ("news")?Is it compulsory or not?

Comment: @user6789978 It is a sample topic that I am using, you can use any topic name that is relevant for your application.

Comment: But it is unrecommended to use this solution if you are sending user specific data, because those could eventually be sent to a topic of multiple user. How do you deal with this without using topics ? Do you have to create types of notifications in backend and filter each type on the client side depending on what the user has checked or not (in local storage / shared preferences) ?

Comment: _"These notifications will be handled by the system if the app is in the background..."_ says the documentation, but is a lie. You app will be woke up for a short time. You can try it by logging the constructor of your `FirebaseMessagingService` implementation to verify it.